# Junção de listas em Python

Tags: python, lista

Como juntar duas listas em Python para formar uma única lista ? Por exemplo, eu tenho essa lista `[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]` e quero junta-la com `[[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]`.

Eu quero que o resultado dessa junção seja a seguinte lista:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Porém ele está ficando dessa forma:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Utilize o método [extend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711/10746978) da lista:

```
a = [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
b = [[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]
a.extend(b)
print(a)
```

Que retorna o valor desejado:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Explicação:

O método extend adiciona todos os itens do iterável que você passa como parâmetro (no caso a segunda lista) à lista original.
O método append, por sua vez, simplesmente adiciona o objeto que inteiro passado por você ao final da lista.

Answer (score 3):

Basta você utilizar o método [extend](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/extend.html) para realização a junção de uma lista com outra. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
lista1 = [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
lista2 = [[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]

lista1.extend(lista2)
print(lista) # [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

O `extend` é um método que recebe como argumento um iterável e adiciona seus elementos à lista. Isso significa que podemos utilizar o método passando como argumento listas, tuplas, dicionários e outros tipos de objetos que sejam iteráveis.

```
lista_principal = [1, 2, 3]
dicionario = {"comida": "pizza", "altura": 1.76}
tupla = ("Cachorro", "Bola")

lista_principal.extend(dicionario)
lista_principal.extend(tupla)
```

Note que o método `extend` não retorna uma nova lista, ele adiciona os elementos modificando diretamente o objeto. Então se você deseja realizar a junção para obter uma lista diferente, terá que copiar o objeto utilizando o método [copy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-copy-method/).